# Cloudstack System VM Networking not working

Tags: kvm, apache-cloudstack, netplan

I've set up a CloudStack testing environment using two VMs: VM 1 has Ubuntu, NFS and KVM installed. VM 2 has Cloudstack installed.

The issue is, that the generated system VMs don't seem to be able to connect to the internet. They are shown as 'running', however, the Agent status is 'unknown'. When connecting to the VM via ssh, I found out that it is unable to access the internet (eg. the gateway 10.10.10.254). The entire project is located in the subnet 10.10.10.0/24. The KVM Hosts netplan config looks as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    ens224:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    cloudbr0:
      macaddress: 00:50:56:82:b6:a7
      interfaces: [ens192]
      addresses: [10.10.10.30/24]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 10.10.10.254
        metric: 100
        on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.10.10.254]
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: false
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    cloudbr1:
      macaddress: 00:50:56:82:cf:64
      interfaces: [ens224]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
```

My first guess is that the 'cloudbr1' bridge is not working properly.
The system VM template has already been re-generated multiple times. The check script inside the VM shows the following output:

> root@s-302-VM:~# /usr/local/cloud/systemvm/ssvm-check.sh
> ================================================
> First DNS server is  10.10.10.254
> PING 10.10.10.254 (10.10.10.254): 56 data bytes
> 92 bytes from 10.10.10.36: Destination Host Unreachable
> 92 bytes from 10.10.10.36: Destination Host Unreachable
> --- 10.10.10.254 ping statistics ---
> 2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
> WARNING: cannot ping DNS server
> route follows
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0         10.10.10.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth2
> 9.9.9.9         10.10.10.254    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth1
> 10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
> 10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
> 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
> ================================================
> ERROR: DNS not resolving cloudstack.apache.org
> resolv.conf follows
> nameserver 10.10.10.254
> nameserver 9.9.9.9
> nameserver 10.10.10.254
> nameserver 9.9.9.9

My Cloudstack config:
The zone has been configured as "advanced zone". Zone network settings:
Guest CIDR: 172.16.1.0/16
DNS: -> Same as in the vm check script above
Pod GW: 10.10.10.254
Pod Netmask: /24

Are there any ideas on what could be the issue?

I already tried the following:

1. recreated the VM template multiple times
2. Removed the 'cloudbr1' bridge
3. Added a second network adapter and mounted it to the 'cloudbr1' interface -> current state
4. Destroyed and regenerated system VMs multiple times
5. Rebooted both the host and the management server